# How to replicate the dialog functionality of jQuery UI in Jetpack?

Tags: jquery-ui, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to get a very basic and simple dialog in my Javascript, actually I'm trying to replicate something very similar to this example from jqueryui website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
           $("#dialog").dialog({
                   bgiframe: true,
                   height: 140,
                   modal: true
           });
   });
   </script>

<div class="demo">
 <div id="dialog" title="Basic modal dialog">
   <p>Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because it dims out the page content.</p>
 </div>
```

...

In order to achieve this I run a function testJQ but I cannot get the desired effect. The div and its inner p is added and I can see the contents of p but I cannot see "Basic modal dialog" and I cannot move it around the page. Am I missing something? Here is my code:

```
function testJQ() {
   var doc = jetpack.tabs.focused.contentDocument;
   var win = jetpack.tabs.focused.contentWindow;

   $.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js",
function(js) {

   var script = doc.createElement("script");
   script.innerHTML = js;
   doc.body.appendChild(script);

   $.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js",
   function(js) {

           var script = doc.createElement("script");
           script.innerHTML = js;
           doc.body.appendChild(script);

       $.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css",
    function(js) {

           var style = doc.createElement("style");
           style.innerHTML = js;
           doc.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(style);

           var script = doc.createElement("script");
           script.innerHTML = js;
           doc.body.appendChild(script);

           script = doc.createElement("script");
           script.innerHTML += '$(function() {';
           script.innerHTML += '$("#dialog").dialog({'
           script.innerHTML += '      bgiframe: true, height: 140, modal: true';
           script.innerHTML += '  });';
           script.innerHTML += '});';
           doc.body.appendChild(script);

           divDialog =  doc.createElement("div");
           divDialog.setAttribute('id', 'dialog');
           divDialog.setAttribute('title', 'Basic Dialog');
           divDialog.innerHTML = '<p>This is the default dialog which is useful
 for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized
 and closed with the X icon.</p>';
           doc.body.appendChild(divDialog);
           });
        });
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem (of course there may be much better, simpler, more elegant ways of achieving this within Jetpack but I couldn't discover that yet):

```
function testJQ() {
var doc = jetpack.tabs.focused.contentDocument;
var win = jetpack.tabs.focused.contentWindow;

$.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js", function(js) {

var script = doc.createElement("script");
script.innerHTML = js;
doc.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(script);

$.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js", function(js) {

    var script = doc.createElement("script");
    script.innerHTML = js;
    doc.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(script);

    $.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css", function(js) {

    var style = doc.createElement("style");
    style.innerHTML = js;
    doc.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(style);

    script = doc.createElement("script");
    script.innerHTML += 'var myDialogFunc = function () {';
    script.innerHTML +=  '$("<div id=dialog title=\\"Basic Dialog\\"> <p>The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the X icon.</p></div>").appendTo("body");';
    script.innerHTML += '$("#dialog").dialog({'
    script.innerHTML += '      bgiframe: true, height: 140, modal: true';
    script.innerHTML += '  });';
    script.innerHTML += '};';
    doc.body.appendChild(script);
    win.wrappedJSObject['myDialogFunc']();      
    });
});
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting the script that invokes the jQuery dialog *before* you're inserting the div of the dialog itself. Therefore `$("#dialog")` matches no elements, so the `dialog()` call on the empty wrapper silently does nothing.

You can get away with this in a simple HTML page because you're using `$(function)` to register an `onready` function that only gets called once the whole document is loaded. But in the Jetpack version, the whole document is already loaded, so inserting the `onready` script gets it called straight away.

If this is an arbitrary third-party document you're inserting content into, this is something you should be very careful with. Loading a large library like jQuery&UI into an arbitrary page that won't be expecting it (rather than one particular page you're targeting) is a bit rude and potentially fragile. Plus what happens if the document already defines an element with id `dialog`? And what if it has style rules that cause the dialog to render in unexpected ways? And so on.

Comment: I have changed the order of inserts, now I'm inserting divDialog, doc.body.appendChild(divDialog); then creating the script element and insert it doc.body.appendChild(script);

However the visible effects are the same. I just see the contents of the p element, I don't see the title of the dialog or I cannot drag it. In additon Firebug complains "syntax error: .ui-helper-hidden { display: none; }\n"

Regarding your concerns about installing jquery, ui and checking for elemement with ids already named as "dialog", I'm aware of risks and I'll take required precautions once I can get this to work.

Comment: You've written the CSS content intended for the `<style>` element into a `<script>` tag by accident. This may have occured due to moving code about and missing a `var` declaration?